# Do the coins have any purpose?

Tags: ski-safari

When you are skiing, you can pick up coins. If you pick up all the coins in one section you get a Gold Rush bonus, but can you actually buy anything with the coins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There didn't used to be any point to them beyond the bonus, but the latest update for iOS introduced a bunch of new things, one of which is an item shop.

From the update release notes:

> Have you ever wondered what those scattered gold coins were for? For the new shop of course! You can use those coins to buy gizmos and powerups to help Sven escape the avalanche. For the more fashion conscious, don’t worry, we’ve added a set of costumes with some bonus challenges too.

The shop currently sells new costumes, powerups, and gizmos.

Comment: Ah. I suspect that Android just hasn't gotten the update yet.

Comment: FYI, as of now, the shop is available on Android. I have no idea when it got the update.